# A package to help with layout generation? Graph paper in the background?

Tags: margins

Once in a while I have to create a layout given by several parameters, such as "left margin 3cm, logo 4 cm from the right margin, 2cm high" etc. Now I use geometry package an other helpers to create a layout, but I need to print out the result in order to check if everything is correct (well, I use Acrobat for that, but not everyone has access to it).

What I am thinking: is there a package to put graph paper with a 1cm grid (and millimeter ticks) in the background, so I could easily check if my layout is correct?

Comment: I'm just adding a `tikz-pgf` tag, because I'm sure someone (not me though) will very soon write down a solution using that package.

Comment: I haven't tried this.  Can you use the wallpaper package with a graph paper as a background image?  There are options in that package to make the background image fit the page.

Comment: @Sony Hehe, I am ignoring the 'tikz-pgf' label and couldn't see my own question after you have added the label. "Why is TeX.SX eating my question" I thought. :)

Comment: @tohecz oh, wrong addressee in my last comment.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think the »[eso-pic](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic)« package provides any easy method to get what you want.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
  grid,
  gridcolor=red!20,
  subgridcolor=green!20
]{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

The grid is customizable in many ways. The package manual has more details.

---

[image]

Comment: Some body seems to have a major problem with this answer. Otherwise it wouldn't have been voted down.

Answer (score 8):

A `TikZ` solution might look like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[very thin, green!20,step=1mm,xshift=7.5mm,yshift=7.5mm] (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
    \draw[very thin, red!20,step=1cm,xshift=7.5mm,yshift=7.5mm] (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am not entirely sure why the shifting is necesarry, but it is if you want the grid to 'start' at the top left.

**Edit:** Here is a robust solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,shift={(current page.north west)}]
  \draw[very thin, blue!10,step=2mm]
  (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
  \draw[very thin, red!20,step=1cm]
  (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The shift appears to be an artifact of the document class. For `memoir`, the xshift is 3.5mm and the yshift 8.0mm. But drawing a line between the SW and NE co-ordinates appears to be correct, relative to the page. ¿Go figure?

Comment: I think we can use `\pgftransformcm{1}{0}{0}{1}{\pgfpoint{7.5mm}{7.5mm}}` to shift the whole picture.

Comment: @percusse: Yeah, I can also apply the shift on the `tikzpicture`, no reason to use the coordinate transformation matrix. I was more wondering why this was necessary in the first place... If I do `\draw (0,0) grid (3,3)` there isn't an offset I need to compensate for, so why is there when using the `current page` node?

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44416/is-memoirs-page-layout-incompatible-with-tikz

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: That looks fine in an `article` though. The rectangle is exactly the page in that case. It also works fine for `memoir` if you remove all of the trimming and margining commands, so...

Comment: @RoelofSpijker: Oh, yes, of course. While I'm not complaining, I think it's a bug/omission, and the definition of "current page" is definitely imprecise, as it currently looks like "from the south west corner of the *stock*, a rectangle that is *paperwidth* by *paperheight*"

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: I certainly agree that the definition is lacking. I don't think that your definition is entirely accurate either though, since that wouldn't explain the shift in the `grid`. Perhaps the `grid` in combination with the `current page` node are causing the issue here. Since the `current page` node without a grid seems to correspond to the correct place in a regular `article` and if I just use the grid as I did in one of my previous comments it starts where expected. Perhaps I will try and analyze this a little further today, if I have the time.

Comment: Yours shifting operations must be changed if you choose another paper size (a4paper for example): `grid` is always at origin. Add `shift={(current page.north west)}` within global options of tikzpicture to solve this problem.

Comment: @RoelofSpijker I have completed your solution with my suggestion...