# Get page location

Tags: tikz-pgf

## I want to get the current location of my text

my mwe follow as:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\def\getx{\tikz[remember picture]\node{\the\pgf@x};}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
one \getx two 

one \getx two
\end{document}
```

but the result is all 0.0pt, what should I do？

Comment: Use `\pgfpictureid` I guess. E.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56510/250119

Comment: Ah, I thought you need to do something with TikZ. If you're currently just using TikZ as a proxy to get page coordinate, yes, use savepos. e.g. [positioning - Determining the position of a symbol/letter in coordinates - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119269/determining-the-position-of-a-symbol-letter-in-coordinates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code to have the definition like this:

```
\makeatletter
\def\getx{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node at (current page.north west){};
\node at (current page.south east){};
    \node (A){\xdef\myx{\the\dimexpr\paperwidth-\pgf@x}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatother
```

This way the coordinates will be absolute according to the page dimensions.