# Rule in textarea every n points

Tags: margins, grid-typesetting

I am currently developing a new layout. This must be typeset on a grid, and every line starts at a multiple of 13bp from the top of the text area. To help me check, I'd like to have rules every 13bp from the top of that area **on every page without interfering with the typeset text**. This is similar to my previous question [A package to help with layout generation? Graph paper in the background?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44381/a-package-to-help-with-layout-generation-graph-paper-in-the-background) where I asked about a grid, but in difference to that question, the grid should start at the top (left) of the text area, not the page.

As far as I see the eso-pic solution is not possible here. What else can I do?

(I am using PDFTeX on Mac and Windows)

[image]

Comment: The `grid` package provides some support.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I don't see how it can help me. Could you extend your comment? How can I use that to draw rules?

Comment: Grundla The grid package provides support for a grid layout. See the reference below for more relevant information about how to avoid LaTeX's strech:

Comment: See the following reference for information on how to avoid LaTeX stretch: `@Article{Bazargan:Radhakrishnan, title = {Removing vertical stretch\emdash mimicking traditional typesetting with {\TeX}}, author = {Bazargan, Kaveh and Radhakrishnan, C.{\thinspace}V.}, journal = {{TUGboat}}, year = {2007}, volume = {28}, number = {1}, pages = {\Range{133}{136}}, url = {http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-1/tb88bazargan.pdf}, }`

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Thanks for the pointer. Interestingly the paper doesn't mention `\pdfsavepos` and such, which I am using now for getting grid typesetting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following solution is independent from the output routine and uses a `eso-pic` like approach:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{atbegshi,picture}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \put(\dimexpr
      \ifodd\value{page}\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi + 1in\relax,
      -\dimexpr\topmargin + 1in + \headheight + \headsep\relax){%
      \begin{picture}(0,0)%
        \setlength{\unitlength}{13bp}%
        \setlength{\dimen0 }{0pt}%
        \@whiledim\dimen0<\dimexpr\textheight+1sp\relax\do{%
          \put(0,-\dimen0){\line(1,0){\textwidth}}%
          \addtolength{\dimen0 }{\unitlength}%
        }%
      \end{picture}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\setlength{\topskip}{13bp}
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   % \baselineskip to 13bp for \normalsize
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xipt{13bp}%
   % the following values are taken from size11.clo.
   \abovedisplayskip 11\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus6\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI
}
% \parskip without glue:
% \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
% or with positive \parskip:
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{13bp}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Example]

Comment: Thanks once again! I think I will make a separate package from that. Great solution!

Answer (score 11):

Something like this (I also changed baselineskip and parskip to the grid)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt{13bp}
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\normalsize
\setlength\parskip{13bp}

\def\@oddhead{%
\setlength\unitlength{13bp}
\raisebox{-\topskip}{\begin{picture}(0,0)%
\multiput(0,0)(0,-1){40}{\line(1,0){30}}%
\end{picture}}\hfill}
\makeatother

\def\a{One two three four five. }
\def\b{\a\a Red green blue. \a\a}
\def\c{\b\b Black white. \b\a\b}


\begin{document}

\c

\c

\c

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

That are simple lines, can also be done with `\rule`, package `pict2e` or something similiar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido}

\begin{document}
\setlength\baselineskip{13bp}\noindent%
\multido{\iA=0+13}{45}{\psline[linecolor=gray](0,-\iA bp)(\linewidth,-\iA bp)}%
%
foo\\
bar\\
baz\\
foobar\\
foobarbaz

\end{document}
```

[image]

and the same with `\rule`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter%
\newdimen\tempL%
\setlength\baselineskip{13bp}\noindent%
\makebox(0,0)[t]{\multido{\iA=0+13}{40}{%
\put(0,-\strip@pt\tempL){\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}}%
\advance\tempL by 13bp}}
\makeatother%
%
foo\\
bar\\
baz\\
foobar\\
foobarbaz

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be great to extend the solution so that every page will have the grid in the background. *Feature request :-)*