# grid for textpos layout

Tags: textpos

This could be a too obvious question.

I'm trying to lay things out on a page and I'm having to recompile a lot. I'd like to layout a grid using `\TPHorizmodule` and `\TPVertmodule` (from the `textpos` package) as the reference which will help me lay out my document. I've seen some 'grid' suggestions but I'm struggling to understand them.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44381/) can be of interest, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one possibility using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newcommand\Mygrid{%
\tikz[
  remember picture,
  overlay,
  yscale=-1,
  xstep=\TPHorizModule,ystep=\TPVertModule,
  yshift=13pt,xshift=4pt]
  \draw (current page.north west) grid (current page.south east);}

\begin{document}
\Mygrid
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've added a link to this answer to the `textpos` documentation.

Comment: Why yshift 13pt and xshift 4pt?