# Align TikZ grid with geometry crop marks

Tags: tikz-pgf, geometry, crop

I am drawing a grid on top of the `layout` defined with `geometry`.

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    showcrop,
    paper = a4paper,
    layout = a5paper,
    layoutoffset={1cm,1cm}
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\makeatletter
% Code from:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85064/grid-for-textpos-layout
\newcommand\rectangulargrid[2]{%
\tikz[
  remember picture,
  overlay,
  yscale=-1,
  xstep=\Gm@layoutwidth/#1,ystep=\Gm@layoutheight/#2,
  xshift= -\Gm@layouthoffset, yshift=-\Gm@layoutvoffset,
  ]
  \draw ($(current page.north west) - (\Gm@layouthoffset, \Gm@layoutvoffset)$) grid 
($(current page.north west)+ (\Gm@layoutwidth, \Gm@layoutheight) + (\Gm@layoutwidth/#1, \Gm@layoutheight/#2) $);}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\rectangulargrid{16}{16}
\end{document}
```

I don't know why the grid lines are not aligned with the crop marks.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I achieve the same effect drawing the lines myself

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    showcrop,
    paper = a4paper,
    layout = a5paper,
    layoutoffset={1cm,1cm}
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\makeatletter
\newcommand\rectangulargrid[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,
  overlay,
  yscale=-1,
  ]
  \draw[fill=red] ($(current page.north west) 
  + (\Gm@layouthoffset, \Gm@layoutvoffset)
  $)
  circle (5pt);
  \draw ($(current page.north west) 
  + (\Gm@layouthoffset, \Gm@layoutvoffset)
   $) -- + (0,-3cm);
  \draw ($(current page.north west) 
  + (\Gm@layouthoffset, \Gm@layoutvoffset)
   $) -- + (-3cm,0);

   \foreach \x in {0,...,#1}
       {
         \draw 
         ($
         (current page.north west) 
         + (\Gm@layouthoffset, \Gm@layoutvoffset)
         + \x*(\Gm@layoutwidth/#1, 0)
         $)
         -- +(0,\Gm@layoutheight);
       }

   \foreach \y in {0,...,#2}
       {
         \draw 
         ($
         (current page.north west) 
         + (\Gm@layouthoffset, \Gm@layoutvoffset)
         + \y*(0,\Gm@layoutheight/#2)
         $)
         -- +(\Gm@layoutwidth, 0);
       }


\end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\rectangulargrid{16}{16}
\end{document}
```