# How to fit characters (numbers) into a graph paper?

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

I want to print some calculations into a graph paper (just some easy calculations like adding some numbers...).

An (ugly) example with a tabular:

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{10}{r|}}\hline
 &   &   &   &  &   &   & &  &  \\\hline
 &   & 1 & + &  & 1 & = & &  & 2\\\hline
 & 1 & 1 & + &  & 1 & = & &  1 & 2\\\hline
 & 1 & 1 & + & 1& 1 & = & &  2 & 2\\\hline
 &   &   &   &  &   &   & &  &  \\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

There are some solutions to print a graph paper/squared paper:

- http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/2639/wie-kann-ich-kastchenpapier-zeichnen
- http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/graph-paper/
- [A package to help with layout generation? Graph paper in the background?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44381/a-package-to-help-with-layout-generation-graph-paper-in-the-background)
- http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphpap

So I tried to find a solution with a graph paper, but I have problems to write the text into the squared boxes.

My solution up to now:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a6paper]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{gridypos}
\newenvironment{squaredpaper}[2][0.5cm]{% 
  \setcounter{gridypos}{#2}
  \newcommand\gridtext[2][\relax]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{\relax}}{}{
         \setcounter{gridypos}{#2}
        \addtocounter{gridypos}{-##1}
        \addtocounter{gridypos}{1}
    }
    \node[anchor=west] at (0,0) [yshift=\value{gridypos}*#1-.5*#1]{##2};  %fixme one box per character(including spaces)
    \addtocounter{gridypos}{-1}%Next \gridtext one line lower
  }
  %Make the grid
  %Source: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/2639/wie-kann-ich-kastchenpapier-zeichnen
  \begin{tikzpicture}[gray,step=#1]
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro\anzahl{(\linewidth-\pgflinewidth)/#1} % maximale Anzahl Kaestchen pro Zeile
     \draw (0,0) rectangle (\anzahl*#1,#2*#1) (0,0) grid (\anzahl*#1,#2*#1);
  }{
   \end{tikzpicture} 
}

\begin{document} 
  \begin{squaredpaper}{20}
    %Start on top line and go down.
    \gridtext{ 1+ 1= 2}
    \gridtext{ 1+ 2= 3}
    \gridtext{ 1+ 3= 4}
    \gridtext{ 1+10=11}
    %Make fix positions
    \gridtext[10]{10+10=20}  %Start in line 10
    \gridtext[15]{15+10=25}  %Start in line 15
    \gridtext[18]{18+10=28}  %Start in line 18
  \end{squaredpaper}

\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

There are two missing things:

- The macro \gridtext should get a 2nd parameter to define the x-pos (I think that's something I can make on my own if my other problem is solved)
- The text does not fit into the squared boxes (one character (number, operator or space) per box)

There are some ideas how I can do it, but I have no idea, how to do it:

- parse the parameter and position character by character into its box.
- Use a monospace font with the exact length of the optional parameter of my squaredpaper-environment.

Remarks:

- The spaces in the \gridtext parameter should be respected (and if this is to difficult I could use ~ as placeholder.)
- Up to now I don't want to add a text, but maybe a *-variant of \gridtext to add text would be fine (but I think, that's something I could do on my own if I need it).

Comment: Do you want one character per box, two, or what exactly?

Comment: One character (number, space or operator) per box.

Comment: You realize that the font will not be "naturally" spaced for that solution, since you are, in essence forcing the height allocated to a character to equal the width allocated for the character.

Comment: Yes, that's ok. It would be ok to use a monospaced font, but I need a specific size for it. -- Hmm, one idea as solution: Use a monospaced font and set the box with to 1em of this font?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I did add spaces manually to the input by way of `~`.  While the macro could be written to intercept a single space in the input between characters, all of LaTeX's parsing mechanisms short of `verbatim` will read multiple spaces as a single space.  Therefore, using `\` or `~` makes sense as the right approach for hard spacing.

The result of `\gridtext` is achieved by parsing the input one character at a time, and setting it in a box the size of the unit-grid cell.

The macro `\gridtext` now has a 2nd mandatory argument that specifies the horizontal offset in squares.

EDITED to us `\obeyspaces`, rather than requiring the use of hard spaces in the `\gridtext` argument.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a6paper]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{gridypos}
\newenvironment{squaredpaper}[2][.5cm]{\obeyspaces% 
  \setcounter{gridypos}{#2}
  \newcommand\gridtext[3][\relax]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{\relax}}{}{
         \setcounter{gridypos}{#2}
        \addtocounter{gridypos}{-##1}
        \addtocounter{gridypos}{1}
    }
%\tmp@dim0=#1\relax%
    \node[anchor=west] at (-.15,0) [yshift=\value{gridypos}*#1-.5*#1]{%
      \hspace{##2\dimexpr#1\relax}\spaceout{#1}{##3}};  %fixme one box per character(including spaces)
    \addtocounter{gridypos}{-1}%Next \gridtext one line lower
  }
  %Make the grid
  %Source: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/2639/wie-kann-ich-kastchenpapier-zeichnen
  \begin{tikzpicture}[gray,step=#1]
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro\anzahl{(\linewidth-\pgflinewidth)/#1} % maximale Anzahl Kaestchen pro Zeile
     \draw (0,0) rectangle (\anzahl*#1,#2*#1) (0,0) grid (\anzahl*#1,#2*#1);
  }{
   \end{tikzpicture} 
}
\newcommand\spaceout[2]{\def\charwd{#1}\spaceouthelp#2\relax\relax\relax}
\def\spaceouthelp#1#2\relax{%
  \ifx#1\relax\else%
    \makebox[\charwd]{#1}%
    \spaceouthelp#2\relax%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document} 
\ttfamily%\scriptsize% WILL WORK IF UNCOMMENTED
  \begin{squaredpaper}{19}
    %Start on top line and go down.
    \gridtext{0}{1+ 1= 2}
    \gridtext{0}{1+ 2= 3}
    \gridtext{0}{1+ 3= 4}
    \gridtext{0}{1+10=11}
    %Make fix positions
    \gridtext[10]{3}{10+10=20}  %Start in line 10
    \gridtext[15]{4}{15+10=25}  %Start in line 15
    \gridtext[18]{5}{18+10=28}  %Start in line 18
  \end{squaredpaper}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the size is changed to `\scriptsize`, it still works.

[image]

If the grid size is changed (e.g., `\begin{squaredpaper}[.4cm]{19}`), it still works:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks. I will use it with ~ - so I can align the output in my editor. I think I will accept your answer after a latency to give the possibility for other answers.