# How to fit numbers and mathematical operators into a graph paper in 2024?

Tags: math-mode, grids

As a math teacher, I'm looking for a way to write mathematical calculations on graph paper so that every number or operator (+,-,*,:, =) fits into a box.

I found [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228846/how-to-fit-characters-numbers-into-a-graph-paper) about this, but I'm having problems with the mark (\cdot) with this approach.

But I'm also wondering, since the above thread is 8 years old, whether there will be a new approach/package in 2024?

Comment: Can you please add a short code, whcih compiles, with your attempt? And may be a screenshot, e.g. for your ideal final result? Thank you

Comment: "Question is old" is usually not a valid excuse to re-ask a question, it causes question fragmentation on the site --- in particular, **if someone decides to post a new package on this question, people coming across the old question will not be able to find the package**. That having said, it's true that it's not very straightforward to understand how to adapt the original answer (using a braced group `{$\cdot$}` works), and because of SE limitation there is little way to "re-ask" or "bump" another person's question.